# Set Sprite Renderer width to specific distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to resize the sprite by the given distance like this:

```
float range = 5;

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    // my problem is that i want to change this sprite 
    // as same distance range in the update method

    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().transform.localScale = range;
}

void update()
{
    if (Vector2.Distance(monster.transform.position, transform.position) < 
        range)
    {
        // do something
        // on the first position enter the range
    }
}
```

I want a way to convert distance units to image size to make the image same size as distance like
       `circle.transform.localScale=Vector2.Distance(monster.transform.position,
    transform.position);`

The sprite is of a circle, so the width and the height should match the distance by then end of the operation.

Comment: Which distance along the sprite renderer do you want to be the same as the distance? The width? The height? The diagonal? Your question is unclear.

Comment: both width and height i have a circle sprite

Comment: this means diagonal right? @Ruzihm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, you should use `GetComponent` only when necessary. It is an expensive operation. It's best to cache results when possible:

```
public SpriteRenderer mySpriteRenderer;

...

// e.g., in Awake()
mySpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
```

To answer your question, what you can do is get what the current `bounds.size.x` is at the current scale and compare it to the distance you want to match. Then, you can change the local scale to adjust the scale depending on the ratio between the current size and the goal size:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    float goalDistance = Vector2.Distance(monster.transform.position, transform.position);

    float currentSize = mySpriteRenderer.bounds.size.x;

    float goalScaleRatio = goalDistance/currentSize;

    transform.localScale *= goalScaleRatio;
}
```

Comment: i have to Multiply goalScaleRatio by 2 to make it in the same size idk why